# Why half coversed or coversed trigonometric functions are being deprecated?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, math-history

As you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Historical_shorthands) there are some names for some trigonometric functions that I can't find in any text or math related papers today.

In my opinion this kind of approach will also make it easier to reason about practical problems that can be solved with a trigonometric approach, in particular this set of functions makes it clearer on why the definition *cyclometric functions* exist.

So why this good old approach is not being considered anymore ?

Comment: Mainly because with modern calculators we dont need tables anymore ...  . Many of the old deprecated functions existed so that one could table them!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sometimes it's more user-friendly to focus on one thing than another, even when the two might be otherwise mechanically equivalent with necessarily identical answers (e.g.: finding the sagitta [i.e: versin] of a ring, rather than the radius minus the cosine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not deprecated; they're largely just forgotten.

In the present day, trigonometry is taught in courses for non-mathematically inclined people who have no desire to take a math course except in order to get rewarded with a good grade for obeying and working hard.  They do not suspect that mathematics is a subject in which one derives things logically from other things and that one knows that something is true by understanding its derivation, rather than by being handed a dogma by authorities.  They bring in tuition money.  It's a racket.  Racketeers get paid to pretend that that is education.  If you tell the truth to such (using the term loosely) students, that mathematics is an intellectual endeavor, they complain that other instructors don't require them to know that.

Textbooks written for *that* kind of audience is where people learn trigonometry nowadays, including many people who actually want to understand mathematics.

It is largely forgotten that there is actually such a thing as an advanced trigonometry book for an audience consisting of mathematicians.  Some of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=trigonometry&sa=X&ei=-1V2U9XYLIOUyAT77oGwCw&ved=0CCIQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1800%2Ccd_max%3A1930&tbm=bks) are of that sort.

Comment: I'm actually more of a programmer and I think that there is still a lot of value in this even today, in fact I spent a lot of time trying to figure out a good way to compute trigonometric functions ( without tables or more common and unoptimized approaches ) but I didn't had any idea about this, I'm quite sure that with this notions I would have been able to find Bhaskara or Padé approx much quicker, or just reasoning about what I was trying to do in a simpler way. Probably there are even better approx. I didn't downvote this btw.

Comment: (I didnt downvote) In what sense do you think this answers the question?  Would it have any value to bring back versed function to be used today? I thought they mainly existed to make tables, simplifying practical use. With calculators we dont need so many tables!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen yes but 1) if you are a programmer you still have to write trigonometric functions in such a way that your hardware will be able to compute them, which means reducing this obscure functions in terms of additions and multiplications basically 2) to use math the right way you have to identify the functions or the set of functions that can solve your problem, plus if you manage to solve more problems with the same functions, it's good starting point for possible optimizations. It's about both your mindset and how to implement things.

Comment: user2485710:  Yes, but the versed functions are such as $\cos \theta +1$, I dont seee how they help you with what you talk about!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen : You could post part of your comment as an answer if you expanded it somewhat.  If the process of table-making is served by those functions, might they also contribute to understanding the software used in calculators, etc.? $\qquad$